# RealmSwift Data Filtering

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Let say i have many city object.So,city ID will be my primary key because they can't be duplicate.There will be the same city name,but,different ID and different ShopAddress.Here is my results from json which was from my backend

```
{
     "CityName" : "NewYork",
     "ID" : 65,
     "CityCode" : "NY",
     "ShopAddress" : "NO.7\/8 17th quarter, 27th Street, LiverPool Township, NewYork."

},
{
    "CityName" : "NewYork",
    "ID" : 89,
    "CityCode" : "NY",
    "ShopAddress" : "NO.7\/8 17th quarter, 40th Street, West Stadium, NewYork."
},
{
    "CityName" : "Maimi",
    "ID" : 150,
    "CityCode" : "MI",
    "ShopAddress" : "NO.7\/8 17th quarter, 40th Street, West Stadium, Maimi."
}...etc
```

Here is my realm object

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class StoreList: Object {

dynamic var storeID : String = ""
dynamic var cityCode : String = ""
dynamic var cityName : String = ""
dynamic var shopAddress :String = ""

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "storeID"
}

}
```

How to get the data of CityNames and appropriate shop address which was concerned with each CityNames?

```
for (var i = 0; i <= cityname.count; i++) {
        cityItems.append("City Names from realm")
        actualPositions.append(-1)

        var items = [String]()
        for (var i = 0; i < cityName["Newyork"].shopaddress.count; i++) {
            items.append("the locations shop address of each item from each cities")
        }

        self.locationItems.append(items)
    }
```

I want to do that because I want to show like that at my accordion table view.[image]

The above code i write is just an example.There will be many mistake.But,i really do need help with filtering.Any Help?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You seen my screenshot right?That is what i want to do.But,i need to get the data first which is save into realm database.There will be many cities.Each cities will include shops address.Cities may be duplicate,but cities id won't be duplicate.

Comment: Ah so you want to display the shops (if there are some available for the city) beneath your city?

Comment: Yeah,correct.But,i need to show city for appropriate shop.you will see at my result json.

Comment: Ah I get it... How are the shops connected with the city?

Comment: One City Many shops and there will be many cities at my country.

Comment: I mean programmatically, which key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103385/discussion-between-6245htarwara-and-anokrize).

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is my solution:

firstly you loop through your objects and get all the cities and put all of them into an array. You also look for duplicated cities so that you have one section for every city:

```
var cities = [string]()
var items = [int]()

// loop through your realm objects
for (var i = 0; i <= RealmObjects.count; i++) {

   // add every city to your array if it isn't already in your array
   if !cities.contains(RealmObjects.CityName) {
      cities.append(RealmObjects.CityName)
      items.append(1)
   }
   else {
      // get index of city
      let indexOfCity = cities.indexOf(RealmObjects.CityName)
      // get number of shops for the city
      var numberOfShops = cities[indexOfCity]
      numberOfShops += 1
      // raise items for section by 1
      items[indexOfCity] = numberOfShops
   }

}

// in your tableViewController add these sections as the title of your header
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

// this is your array including the cities
return self.cities

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
// return the number of sections
return self.section.count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
// return the number of rows for one section
return self.items[section] // not sure with this you have to get the current section 

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Add the shops in your section
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.RealmObjects.ShopAddress[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}
```

I didn't try this code... This is the basic approach.
Quick explanation:

1. You have to put the cities into an array (no duplicate of cities)
2. Count the number of shops for one city
3. Set the section appropriate to the cities which are inside the array
4. Set the number of rows for one section for this you should read out the array which counts the shops for one city
5. Set the number of sections
6. At least call the cellForRowAtIndexPath in order to set the text of the cell

Comment: can i meet you back at chat?